# Typescript generics error: 'Conversion may be a mistake'

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a question about Typescipt generics as I don't understand why the compiler throws an error. Here is code:

```
type LengthWise = {
    length: number;
};

function addSuffixFunc<Type extends LengthWise>(a: Type): Type | null {
    console.log('a.length: ', a.length);
    if(typeof a === 'string') {
        return (a + '34') as string as Type;
    } 
    return null;
}
```

In the return statement inside 'if' the compiler throws an error:

> Conversion of type 'string' to type 'Type' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

The compiler throws that the string type and the 'Type' don't overlap each other, but in my opinion this is not true - both the 'Type' and 'string' do have the 'length' property, so every property in 'Type' (which is only 'length') is available in type string, in other words string is castable to 'Type'.
it works though if I first cast it to unknown:

```
return (a + '34') as unknown as Type;
```

Can somebody explain this compiler behavior?

The code in question explains everything.

Comment: `addSuffixFunc<"hello">("hello")`

Comment: @VLAZ the error is inside the function body, not in the usage

Comment: Sure, but usage (by the caller) determines `Type`.  The value `"hello34"` does not conform to [the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"hello"`, thus for `addSuffixFunc<"hello">("hello")` the result is *not* `Type` (since `Type` will be `"hello"`) nor will it be `null`. The function signature is wrong. Guess where that breaks down. Hint: it's in the body.

Comment: @VLAZ But I can use it as `addSuffixFunc<string>("hello")`. Then 'hello34' is assignable to 'string'. And this still doesn't work - compiler error is still there.

Comment: Again, *the caller* determines the generic. If the caller uses `string` it works. If it uses `"hello"` it doesn't work. The generic function is not very "generic" if it doesn't actually work for any generic parameter.

Comment: @VLAZ has correctly identified the situation; nothing stops a caller from writing `addSuffixFunc("foo")`, which will infer `Type` as `"foo"`, and your call signature claims that it will return `"foo" | null`, which is [demonstrably not true](https://tsplay.dev/wQ2e1N).  That's why you have an error; the value `(a + '34')` cannot be known to be `Type` even if `a` is a string.  Do you understand the issue now?  If so someone (maybe @VLAZ) can write up the answer; if not, how can we help explain it better to you?

Comment: @jcalz @VLAZ, yes the answer completely makes sense, and I understand it. One more question which arises for me: Is it possible in this function to return some variable which is different from the argument ? I mean for now it seems like only `return a` would comply to Type. Can you show some example when you don't return `a`, but some different Variable ? Like I tried to do `let b = a + '34'; return b`, so this returns a different variable which is `b`

Comment: A comment section isn't a great place to expand the scope of a question; it's better to [edit] the question or ask a new one.  [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQ28AN) shows one way you could get an output be a different type from the input due to string concatenation.  Traditionally people would use *overloads* to get the effect you describe (but there are caveats), or you could also use generic conditional types (with caveats also), but to discuss this fully isn't really possible here.